# Word-meaning understanding (From Magoosh Flashcard--'Mitigate')

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Here are two plausibly different definitions of the word "Mitigate":

> (1) to make less severe or harsh; (2) to lessen the severity of an offense

I don't see why Magoosh lists two meanings for this word because it seems like there's no way to have the difference between them essentially. I suppose (2) is contained in (1) since an offense can be something to be alleviated, to be less severe. Despite this, I don't know if there's a subtle difference, so I would like to consult anyone about it.

In addition, an example for usage of meaning (2) is given in Magoosh as follows:

> If it were not for the mitigating circumstances, he would have certainly lost his job.

**Remark:**
I've consulted the Cambridge and the meaning it shows (quoted below) and meaning (1) are very alike, I think.

> to make something less harmful, unpleasant, or bad

Comment: Surely you mean 'If it were **not** for the mitigating circumstances'? The circumstances made whatever crime he committed less blameworthy.

Comment: @KateBunting Ah yeah I missed "not". Have got it revised, thanks